# llvm Branch instruction using SplitBlockAndInsertIfThenElse

Tags: c++11, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to build an LLVM pass that splits the BasicBlock and make a decision using "SplitBlockAndInsertIfThenElse" every time a binary operation is encountered, however this only allows me to split once (split at the 1st binop). could you please help me make it iterate through all the binop instructions?
Knowing that changing the position of "break;" gives me errors when running the pass. same thing happens when I put the "SplitBlockAndInsertIfThenElse" in a nested loop.
Here is my code:

```
for (inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I)

 {

 if (auto *op = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(&*I)) 
 {
   IRBuilder<> Builder(op);
   Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);
   Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1); 
   Value *xpv = Builder.CreateAlloca(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(llvm::getGlobalContext()), nullptr, "x");  
   Value *xpv2 = Builder.CreateAlloca(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(llvm::getGlobalContext()), nullptr, "x2");

   Value *add1 = Builder.CreateAdd(lhs, rhs);
   Value *add2 = Builder.CreateAdd(lhs, rhs);
   Value *icmp1 = Builder.CreateICmpEQ(add1, add2);

   TerminatorInst *ThenTerm , *ElseTerm ;

   SplitBlockAndInsertIfThenElse(icmp1, op, &ThenTerm, &ElseTerm,nullptr);
   Builder.SetInsertPoint(ThenTerm);
   Value *xp1 = Builder.CreateStore(add1, xpv);
   Builder.SetInsertPoint(ElseTerm);
   break ;  
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `break` at all?

Comment: I tried not using it, it gives compilation errors

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: You are modifying the instruction list that you are currently loop through. This is never a good idea because iterators become invalid when the list is modified.  Since you split your basic block you split your instruction list and most likely run out of the valid memory region of the list. Most likely you'll end up crashing all the time you run your pass.

Answer (score 0):

Don't perform concurrent iteration and modification of the instruction list. Iterate until you find the first instruction you care about, then **break** out of the loop, perform the modification, and restart the loop, starting from the next instruction after the split-before one (so the next instruction after `op`, in your case).